# advanced screen settings

Tags: lubuntu, hdmi, multiple-monitors

I have installed lubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with hdmi output. Now I want to show some content on my tv, but I'm struggling with the right settings.

The way I would like it:

1. I would like to have the taskbar on the bottom of my laptop screen (the bottom one of the two screens). Right now it is placed on my tv (the upper one).
2. And I would like it if I move a window to the tv screen in order to watch it full screen, that it actualy show up full screen on my tv, and not on my laptop again.

Does anybody have experience with this and have some direction for me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get number one done. Go to system prefrences monitor settnigs. To fix the first one you need to right click on the panel click panel settings.
Or run `lxpanelctl config` to bring up the settings of the panel. Then select the monitor two in your case to get it to the bottom.

To get the large window on the tv are you moving it to the tv and then laucnh it on the tv? That is the expected behavior anything else might be a bug.